# Tag SELECT está duplicando com MaterializeCSS e AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, html-select, materialize

Então, possuo em uma view um select, conforme o codigo abaixo:

```
    <select ng-model="Dashboard.FiltroChamadas.grupoSelecionado">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Selecione um grupo</option>
      <option ng-repeat="grupo in Dashboard.grupos" value="{{grupo._id}}">{{grupo.nome}}</option>
    </select>
```

no meu controller tenho o seguinte codigo:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul.tabs').tabs();
  $('select').material_select();
});
```

O problem é que este select está sendo duplicado. Ele aparece uma vez com o estilo do Materialize e novamente abaixo sem estilo algum(html puro). Já tentei nao fazer a inicialização conforme está ali e na documentação do materialize.. desta forma a página vem carregada certo, porém ao selecionar um item do select ele é duplicado. Não faço idéia do que esta ocorrendo...Help

Answer (score 1):

Podem ser as versões do Materialize que você está utilizando.

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/css/materialize.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.6/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Segue link do [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/akXcTf3kooOTMF4WrfNF?p=preview) funcionando.